# Prepend container to all JQuery selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I'm working on a web application where the same JSP page is loaded to multiple areas of the same page with different parameters.  Dynamic javascript is built for each section, the problem is when I use jQuery selectors on class name I'm returned all elements with that class across all of the instances of that JSP.

What I would like to do is in that dynamic javascript file somehow override the base $('.classname') style selector to do something like... $('<%=containerDiv%> .className') with out re-factoring all of the code to do this.

All of the code I'm trying to change is encapsulated into one javascript object so I would be wanting to do this in the constructor.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

In pseudo code what I'm looking for is...

```
$(regularConstructor) = $(localVar + ' ' + regularConstructor);
```

Comment: Is the goal to not change any existing code? Can you change the params that get passed to the constructor? If so, pass the parent to the constructor and then see the answer posted by Flops.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to avoid changing the code.  See response to Flops' answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try not to generate, but just give a context in selector as a second argument.

This would be something like this:

```
var widget = $("<div/>"); //Creating dom node
/*
  Or you can get it by your dinamic id: 
  widget = $("<%=containerDiv%>");
*/
widget.html("<div class='classname'>111</div>"); //Filling it with content
widget.appendTo("body"); //Inserting it to document
$(".classname", widget).fadeOut(); //working with elements inside your widget
```

And than you have a Dom node link that you can use in your script without conflict in selectors.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do, but seeing as the same code is re-used many times on the page, I would like only the constructor to be different, the route I know will work is putting the "container" into a var and prepending it if it exists.  I'd like to avoid doing this tho as the js file I'm talking about is over 1,000 lines..